# SonarQube dependency check sonar plugin

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, sonarqube

I'm having issues with displaying vulnerabilities on SonarQube. Here are the steps I followed:

1. Installed dependency-check-sonar-plugin version 1.0.3 on SonarQube.
2. Configured dashboard to include Vulnerabilities widjet.
3. Generated dependency report using: mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:1.3.6:check -Dformat=XML.
4. Report was placed into [project]/target/dependency-check-report.xml
5. Ran sonar task: org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar
   Task completed successfully but I don't see data in the Vulnerabilities widjet.
   Anyone has idea what could prevent plugin from seeing report?

Thanks in advance!
Rada

Comment: What did you do so far to troubleshoot this ? (also: SonarQube version ? logs of the dependency check? logs of the analysis and command invoked ?)

Comment: The issue was resolved. Thanks a ton to the creator of the plugin who pointed me into the right direction!

Comment: You should share the solution with the rest of the community :) (in StackOverflow you can answer your own question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve the issue I contacted Steve Springett, creator of the plugin. He has great end-to-end [examples](https://github.com/dependency-check/dependency-check-sonar-plugin/tree/master/examples/single-module-maven) of how plugin should be configured.

I added  `<sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath>${dependency.check.report.dir}/dependency-check-report.xml</sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath>` to the properties of my pom and used following two plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <format>XML</format>
        <outputDirectory>${dependency.check.report.dir}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: it would be nice if the maven plugin uploads to the xml to sonarqube. not all the setups are on the same host.

Comment: The XML format is deprecated and the sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath has been replaced with sonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath and sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath